# Help identifying insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology, pest-control, pesticide

I live in Milan, Italy in the city center.
I started seeing this insect in August after a long vacation. In this periods the temperature inside the house went up to 36°C (temperatures here range from -1°C to +35°C in average).

I find it mostly in my kitchen in particular in a cabinet where i store food.

The size is about 3mm in length and less than 1mm in width.

What is its name so I can research more about it (i.e., does it pose any risk to my health or to my belongings in the house?)?

I have tried to use a common bug spray to get rid of it (i.e., emptied the cupboard, got rid of food that was not sealed and sprayed the cabinet profusely). It was unsuccessful as after 10-15 days it came back.

Is there a more appropriate bug spray to get rid of this insect?

Should I be looking for nests or eggs?

[image: Picture of the subject. Dead, upside down.]

**EDIT**

Additional close-up pictures with a cheap microscope.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome back to the Biology Stack. Unfortunately that photo is too low quality to say anything about the insect, we would at least need to see photos of the back of the insect and they would need to have higher resolution to properly identify it. Your best bet is to contact a local pest control company and have them come out and do an assessment.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have added some pictures, I don’t know if they are very helpful.

Comment: Much better. Something in the beetle family I think, but there are a few experts on here, who I will leave it to.

Comment: Can't give a species but my first thought would be a grain/flour beetle; you might check your food again, especially any grain, flour, cereal, etc. They may be able to enter through packaging, depending on the packaging type. I wouldn't think you need any pesticides, just to identify the infested food and wipe up any remaining beetles/eggs/larvae, but if the problem persists you could consult a local expert.

Comment: Would you know what kind of bug spray should I try before I call pest control?

Comment: I don't think a spray is going to help. If I'm right, they're in your food. Spraying outside the food doesn't get the ones that are in your food. Spraying your food directly is not wise because you don't want to be eating the stuff you're spraying. You'll need to find what is infested before you continue. If there are beetles to wipe up, I'd think just a soapy rag is going to be better than any insecticide spray.